# Rounded triangular arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to use Tikz to draw a rounded triangular tip as in the attached screenshot.

`Triangle Cap[]` is too sharp and `Round Cap[]` doesn't slope gradually enough.
I've tried using a `Stealth` arrow head resized to the width of the line but that doesn't yield an appropriate result.
Essentially, I'm looking for an arrow that looks like a slightly rounded pencil: a slightly rounded tip; and a slight curve where the sloping lines meet the horizontal line.

My attempts are as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}


\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{open cap}{open cap}
{\pgfarrowsleftextend{+0pt}\pgfarrowsrightextend{+0.5\pgflinewidth}}
{
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{.5*\pgflinewidth-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  \pgfsetbuttcap
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.5*\pgfutil@tempdimb+0.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpatharc{270}{90}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}

\begin{document}



\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=5pt, color=blue, text = black}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture ]
 \draw[open cap-open cap] (0,0)--node [above] {Rounded ends: end is round as desired but arcs to end rather than straight lines}(10,0);
 \draw[{Triangle Cap[]}-{Triangle Cap[]}] (0,1)--node [above] {Short triangles: right width but join between tip and line is sharp not rounded}(10,1);
 \draw[{Triangle Cap[length=10pt]}-{Triangle Cap[length=10pt]}] (0,2)--node [above] {\scriptsize{Longer triangles: still right width but meeting point between tip and line is still a sharp corner}}(10,2);
 \draw[{Triangle Cap[length=10pt, line cap=round]}-{Triangle Cap[length=10pt, line cap =round]}] (0,3)--node [above] {No difference when specifying "line cap = round"}(10,3);
 \draw[{Stealth [round]}-{Stealth[round]}] (0,4)--node [above] {Round stealth: rounded end and edges of tips; perfect but wider/thicker than the line}(10,4); 
 \draw[{Stealth [width=10pt, round]}-{Stealth[width=10pt, round]}] (0,5)--node [above] {Thinner round stealth: almost perfect but still wider/thicker than the line}(10,5);
 \draw[{Stealth [width=5pt, round]}-{Stealth[width=5pt, round]}] (0,6)--node [above] {Very thin round stealth: starts acting unpredictably; tip extends past end of line}(10,6); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Rounded triangular tip]

Edit:

The following is almost perfect but I'm hoping the corners where the slanted lines meet the horizontal lines would be rounded too.
Thanks to @Qrrbrbirlbel.

[image: Rounded tip]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining new arrow tips can be tedious if done properly. Maybe a slight adjustment to a `round`ed `Triangle` tip suffices.

The value `1.963` is a guesstimate for the angle of 30°. It scales correctly with the line width but changing the angle will lead to a incorrect output. I'd need to study the various keys for arrow tips more to figure out the correct arrangement. (The roundness of the tip makes the math quite annoying.)

The `\pgfarrowssetlineend{.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}` makes the actual line overlap the arrowtip.

You can use the [`line width` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/arrow:keys/line:width) – the one inside the arrow tip's options! – to essentialy adjust the radius of the rounding.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, spy}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.arrows} % for clone and append setup code,
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name  = Stealth X, clone = Stealth,
  append setup code=\pgfarrowssetlineend{.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}}
\pgfset{Triangle X/.tip={Stealth X[inset=+0pt, angle=+60:+2.7pt +3.6]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every path/.append style={line width=4ex},
  connect spies/.append style=blue,
  Tri/.tip={Triangle X[round, angle=30:+0pt +1.963]},
  spy using outlines={%
    circle, magnification=5, size=7mm, connect spies,
    every spy in node/.append style={fill=white}}]
\draw[        Tri             -Tri             ] (0,0) -- +(right:2);
\draw[arrows={Tri[color=green]-Tri}            ] (0,1) -- +(right:2);
\draw[arrows={Tri[color=green]-Tri}, opacity=.5] (0,2) -- +(right:2);
\spy on ( .59, 0.3) in node at (1,-0.2);
\spy on ( .59, 1.3) in node at (1, 0.7);
\spy on ( .59, 2.3) in node at (1, 1.7);
\spy on ( .59, 2.3) in node at (2, 1.7) [magnification=20];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's surprisingly close to what I'm looking for in very elegant code. I was hoping the corners where the slanted lines meet the horizontal line could be slightly rounded too. Is that possible?

Comment: @TheorVHP They are. Take a look at the update of my answer.

Comment: thank you. This is an outstanding solution that I hadn't considered. I agree that the roundedness complicates the math. I'm wondering what the relationship between angle and `+X` term is. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mind clarifying the meaning of each number, e.g. in `inset=+0pt, angle=+60:+2.7pt +3.6` and `angle=30:+0pt +1.963`? Thanks again

Comment: @TheorVHP These are all explained at length [in the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.3.1). The first one is copied from the source as `Triangle` is based on `Stealth` so I define `Triangle X` with the same defaults on `Stealth X`. They all work in tandem in the background.